# Beamer: Automating Black Pages without page numbering

Tags: beamer

I have the following code that I use in beamer to create blank slides that allow me to switch mode in my lectures and do some exercise with the group or something on the blackboard:

```
{ % black page
\setbeamercolor{background canvas}{bg=black}
\begin{frame}
<handout:0>
\end{frame}
```

Regarding this, I have two questions:

1) is there a simpler way (e.g. \insertblackpage) or something
2) if not, how can I create such a command, as I am using this quite a lot
3) is there a way to avoid such black pages been counted with a pagenumber? I am using the following code to create pagenumbers:

```
\setbeamertemplate{footline}
{
  \leavevmode%
  \hbox{%
  \begin{beamercolorbox}[wd=.99\paperwidth,ht=2.25ex,dp=1ex,right]{xxx}%
    \hspace*{6em}
    \insertpagenumber{} \hspace*{1ex}
  \end{beamercolorbox}}%
  \vskip0pt%
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The following code should be what you want:

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\newcommand\insertblackpage{% black page
  \addtocounter{page}{-1}
  \begingroup
  \setbeamercolor{background canvas}{bg=black}
  \setbeamertemplate{navigation symbols}{}
  \begin{frame}<handout:0>\end{frame}
  \endgroup
}

\setbeamertemplate{footline}
{
  \leavevmode%
  \hbox{%
  \begin{beamercolorbox}[wd=.99\paperwidth,ht=2.25ex,dp=1ex,right]{xxx}%
    \hspace*{6em}
    \insertpagenumber{} \hspace*{1ex}
  \end{beamercolorbox}}%
  \vskip0pt%
}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
normal frame 1
\end{frame}

\insertblackpage

\begin{frame}
normal frame 2
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Great! That worked wonderfully. Thank you very much.